# Netlify functions not found on dev server

Tags: netlify, netlify-function

I have followed several blogs and questions related to the same problem I am having. It is exactly like this [question](https://answers.netlify.com/t/netlify-dev-changes-proxy-port-eveytime-it-runs/14773/16). However, I am still having issues.

So, I am running `netlify dev` and trying to access my netlify functions. I have a function in `/netlify/functions/ping`. The function works as intended when I access the randomized port for the netlify functions (something like localhost:55832...).

However, using the `localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/ping` gives me a 404 error.

Here is my /netlify/functions/ping file:

```js
import { Handler } from '@netlify/functions';

const handler: Handler = async (event, context) => {

  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify({ data: "pong" }),
  };
};

export { handler };
```

here is where I am trying to call my function on a page

```js
export default function HomePage() {

  useEffect(() => {
    async function pingpong() {
      const res = await fetch(`/.netlify/functions/ping`);
      console.log(res);
    }

    pingpong();
  }, []);

  return (
...
```

I have also tried to alter my netlify.toml with the following

```
[[redirects]]
from = "/api/*"
to = "/.netlify/functions/:splat"
status = 200
force = true
```

Comment: The netlify functions also work when hosted on Netlify. Just not when running a local dev environment.

Comment: I've decided to move everything to amplify instead and avoid Netlify Functions because they don't seem to work very well

Answer (score 0):

what's start script you use in package.json?

Keep in mind that, to enable Netlify Functions you have to use netlify-cli, i.e. `ntl` command to run on local dev server.

No more specific configuration, just follow docs, and use that simple `netlify/functions/hello.js` example.

Then run using `ntl dev`, you function will be avaiable on `/.netlify/functions/hello`. easy.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having similar issue apply everything listed below:

1. In [yourFunction].js use commonjs syntax - change `export const handler =` to `exports.handler =` and use `require` instead of `import`.
2. Put your function in the 'functions' directory in your root folder NOT 'netlify/functions' BUT keep fetching url the same.
3. Add netlify.toml file to your root directory and put this inside:
   `[build] command = 'npm run build' functions= 'functions' publish = 'dist'`.
4. Don't import Handler like shown in post. You actually don't need '@netlify/functions' to work. If you want to try out if everything works locally, install netlify globally and run command 'netlify login' (to verify your Netlify account) then 'netlify dev'.
5. Here's my example function:

```
import "dotenv/config";
        import Stripe from "stripe";
        const stripe = Stripe(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);  
        
        exports.handler = async (event) => {
          try {
            const { amount } = JSON.parse(event.body);
        
            const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
              amount,
              currency: "usd",
              payment_method_types: ["card"],
            });
        
            return {
              statusCode: 200,
              body: JSON.stringify({ paymentIntent }),
            };
          } catch (error) {
            console.log({ error });
        
            return {
              statusCode: 400,
              body: JSON.stringify({ error }),
            };
          }
        };
```

**Only this solution fixed my problem, hope that it will also fix yours:)**